# How to pass parameter in Laravel Relationship Function within blade?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

**Student.php**

It has many fees

```
class student extends Model{
    public function fees($round){
        return $this->hasMany(fee::class)->where('payment_round','=',$round);
    }
}
```

**Fee.blade.php**

```
@foreach($student->fees("parameter") as $fee)
    {{$fee->myproperty}}
@endforeach
```

How I can pass a parameter to $student->fees("parameter")?

Comment: Why don't you give a try and share us what error you're getting? e.g

`$var = 'Hello'; 
@foreach($student->fees($var) as $fee)
    {{$fee->myproperty}}
@endforeach`

Comment: It doesn't show any error message. It is just empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
@foreach($student->fees($parameter)->get() as $fee)
   {{ $fee->myproperty }}
@endforeach
```

I think you had confused the collection of related models `fees` with the query constructor `fees()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep relationship as simple as possible and add a second method which uses that to get the data you want :

```
<?php

class student extends Model{

    public function fees(){
        return $this->hasMany(fee::class);
    }

    public function getFeeByRound($round)
    {
        return $this->fees()->where('payment_round','=',$round)->get();
    }

}
```

And then you can use this as  :

```
@foreach($student->getFeeByRound($parameter) as $fee)
   {{ $fee->myproperty }}
@endforeach
```